# How to capture what a php function returned and change html elements css

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've made a fairly simple login page, but now I want to test if the login information is correct by submitting the information to a php function.
If that function returns false I need to change some css properties of some elements.
So far I've tried to assign an "onclick" event to the submit button, in the php I assign false to a variable and I return it, later in js script I try to echo de variable to a JS variable so I can check it's value.
This is what I have:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IPS Connected - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\CSS\main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <?php
  if($_POST)
  {
    $result = false;
    return $result;
  }
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="assets/icons/user.png" id="userLogo" alt="user-icon">
      <form method="post">
      <div class="form-div">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-div">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" onclick="checkLogin();" class="btn-login">
      </form>
      <br>
      <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLogin()
    {
        var result = "<?php echo $result?>";
        if(!result)
        {
          var edit_save = document.getElementById("userLogo");
          edit_save.src = "assets/icons/error.png";
        }
    }
  </script>
```

EDIT: I've tried to change the php script to

```
  <?php
if($_POST)
  {
    $result = test();

    function test()
    {
      return false;
    }

  }
    ?>
in the script I've changed it to

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function checkLogin()
      {
        var test = <?php echo $result?>;
        if(!test)
        {
          document.getElementById('userLogo').src="assets/icons/error.png";
        }
        else
        document.getElementById('userLogo').src="assets/icons/user.png";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've did my research... I've posted this because couldn't find anything conclusive on the matter and already tried what I could find,
I'm new to php and javascript, in fact this is my first project using php.
I understand the logic behind what I need to do and I've applied it to what you see on the edit of my topic.
I've written the code myself, sorry but no valid point for that in your answer. The only thing I haven't tried was to create a dynamic css file with php, but since I'm really new to this I don't want to take that aproach just yet. first I need to grasp the basics

Comment: of the interaction between JS and PHP

Comment: The interaction between JS and PHP would be AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how PHP works. It's a preprocessing language.
More over its a server side language and is compiled on the server, whereas JS is a client side language and is copiled on the client's machine.

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <?php
    if($result){
      echo "document.getElementById('userLogo').src='assets/icons/error.png';";
    }else{
      echo "document.getElementById('userLogo').src='assets/icons/user.png';";
    }
  ?>
</script>
```

It would send the JS code according to the value of `$result` and the JS would be compiled on the client.

Comment: is it possible to define the php function in the head section and then call it in the script?